# Multilanguage website in umbraco and content publish dates

Tags: umbraco, multilingual

I have a multilanguage website in umbraco (developed according to this article). My problem is that the english version content was copied to the 'en' node some time after the content in original language was created. The problem is however, that now all news in english have the same date, which is not the equivalent of the original news date. Now my question is: is it possible for the english content (especialy news nodes) to have the same publish/create dates as they are on the original language site and not the date on which they were copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to do a mass update on the publish dates.  There are two packages that I've used that would help you to do this.

First CMSImport (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport)

Set up a file that contains the new date and something unique about each post and you can use it to do a mass update of the dates.

Secondly Content Maintenance Dashboard (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/content-maintenance-dashboard-package)

Which is newer and should allow you to easily check how the changes have been processed.

The free version of both packages should sort you out.